# How to access Word Press (Elementor) code on local machine

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm developing a website using Word Press (Elementor plugin) and I want to create a custom widget. I found a tutorial I want to follow (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ko9i153o_iU), the only problem is that I have no idea how to access the code on my local machine to begin. From what I can tell, everything I'm doing is on the word press website, and the code isn't on my local machine. How do I go about getting the code onto my local machine so I can begin working with it in vscode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to spin up local apache or nginx server and mysql, along with Wordpress. I suggest the app Local:

https://localwp.com/

Then, if you want to copy your production environment (your website), you need to get the files for the theme and any plugins onto your local environment. Local pairs with some hosting providers to make this easy. Otherwise you can install by downloading the files. Some hosting providers give you FTP or SFTP access to your site files. Figure out how you can gain access and download them.

Lastly, if you want, you can copy the database over to your local environment. There is a great plugin called WP Sync DB that does this for free. It can also be a way to push your local environment to your production environment, but I definitely suggest keeping backups if you are going to do that.